# Which authentication layer should be customized in this situation?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, authentication, spring-security

Current Spring application requires very specific way for user authentication:

user get into the application through a form with username(input field) and authentication method(dropdown box) and ..potentially a password(input field) if needed, then the user should be able to log on the application by provided authentication method and credential(username and password may not need if use LDAP etc)

So in this case, I guess the

```
<AuthenticationManager>
    <BASICAuthenticationProvider/>
    <DAOAuthenticationProvider/>
    <LDAPAuthenticationProvider/>
    ......
</AuthenticationManager>
```

does not apply to this scenario. I am new to Spring Security and after little research I found several places may need customization to this situation: `AuthenticationManager`, `AuthenticationProvider`, `PreAuthenticationFilter` etc but don't know there to start.
Then which classes supposed to be overridden? AuthenticationProvider? or Pre-Authentication? or even AuthenticationManager? There seems a lot from Spring security but I just not sure where is the lead. I check on offical doc, but cannot find a solution similar to this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Just update the question, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: What is the "very specific way"? Give us a sample URL please.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch just saying. modify that part as well in the post. The information is get in trough a form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with some thing like this

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

AuthenticationService needs to implement  UserDetailsService (which is the core interface which loads user-specific data.). Here you can override loadUserByUsername method and provide a Dao which can fetch user details form db.